# How to disabled sidebar image on RetroPie?

Tags: pi-3, retropie

[image]

How do I hide the images on the side (highlighted in red ) ?

I want to display the game full screen.

Please advise.

Comment: Not something I know much about but I would guess this is because arcade games have a 4:3 aspect ratio, but you are probably using a standard HD monitor which is 16:9.  To make that occupy the full screen, it either has to be stretched  horizontally or cropped vertically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can hide side bazels using graphical interface:

1. RetroPie Main Menu
2. Retroarch Menu
3. Settings
4. Onscreen display
5. Display Overlay

   - Change to OFF

Or manually editing one or more file using the shell.
In the last case you need to edit `/opt/retropie/emulators/retroarch/retroarch.cfg` file for a change that impact all emulation cores, or single `/opt/retropie/configs/**/retroarch.cfg` emulator configuration files for a per emulator basis change by replacing:

```
input_overlay_enable = true
```

with

```
input_overlay_enable = false
```

Then you still need to change retroarch screen Aspect Ratio, you can do that using graphical interface:

1. RetroPie Main Menu
2. Retroarch Menu
3. Settings
4. Video
5. Scaling
6. Aspect Ratio

   - Change to 16:9 or whatever you need

Remenber to save changes before exit in

4. Configuration File
5. Save Current Configuration

Comment: How do I go into the command line ? When I boot up, I see bunch of games.

Comment: If you don't know how to go in command line I sudgest you to use graphical interface method.
Anyway to go on command line interface you need to quit emulation station by pressing (Start) MENU button on your gamepad and than select -> Quit -> Quit Emulationstation.
Another way, a better way is to enable ssh service using raspbian configuration and than use another PC in the same network to access using SSH, but you can find a lot of informazion on that using google search

Comment: I’ll enabled SSH and do that instead then.

Answer (score 1):

These games were not designed to to be played full screen on an HD tv. The image will come out all stretched and horrible. They play the best in their native resolution.